# Killing child process when parent crashes in python

Tags: python, process, subprocess

I am trying to write a python program to test a server written in C. The python program launches the compiled server using the `subprocess` module:

```
pid = subprocess.Popen(args.server_file_path).pid
```

This works fine, however if the python program terminates unexpectedly due to an error, the spawned process is left running. I need a way to ensure that if the python program exits unexpectedly, the server process is killed as well.

Some more details:

- Linux or OSX operating systems only
- Server code can not be modified in any way

Comment: "due to an error" -- What kind of error?

Comment: Networking errors, Keyboard interrupt, etc.

Comment: [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) is an open-source process management daemon written in Python. The source code might be worth a look if you have the time.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1884941/205521

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I would [`atexit.register`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html) a function to terminate the process:

```
import atexit
process = subprocess.Popen(args.server_file_path)
atexit.register(process.terminate)
pid = process.pid
```

Or maybe:

```
import atexit
process = subprocess.Popen(args.server_file_path)
@atexit.register
def kill_process():
    try:
        process.terminate()
    except OSError:
        pass #ignore the error.  The OSError doesn't seem to be documented(?)
             #as such, it *might* be better to process.poll() and check for 
             #`None` (meaning the process is still running), but that 
             #introduces a race condition.  I'm not sure which is better,
             #hopefully someone that knows more about this than I do can 
             #comment.

pid = process.pid
```

---

Note that this doesn't help you if you do something nasty to cause python to die in a non-graceful way (e.g. via `os._exit` or if you cause a `SegmentationFault` or `BusError`)

Comment: @ire_and_curses -- Thanks for adding the link.  it's appreciated.

Comment: the "nasty case" is the most interesting one )

Comment: I give an option for the "nasty case" in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25542110/kill-child-process-if-parent-is-killed-in-python/25634723#25634723, but it doesn't help here (it requires access to the client source code).