# Subprocess pipe terminal input?

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to write a helper script to shorten some of my project commands.

The script looks like this:

```
import subprocess

def up():
  subprocess.call(['docker-compose', 'up'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
  up()
```

This works, however if I run `ctrl + c`, it will kill the script and not the subprocess.

Is there a way I can make the `subprocess` the priority for all terminal input until it exits?

Comment: `os.system()` probably does that. This doesn't particularly look like a good use case for a Python script, but perhaps your real script has more features.

Comment: take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447603/how-to-kill-a-python-child-process-created-with-subprocess-check-output-when-t

Comment: You must catch `KeyboardInterrupt`, then. https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyboardInterrupt

Comment: @tripleee appreciate the response. My goal is to use this as a helper script that is cross platform. Unfortunately I don't think there is a good x-platform alternative scripting language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this as follows:

```
def up():
  try:
    subprocess.call(['docker-compose', 'up'])
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\n')
```

It appears to do the job.