# How can I start a GUI program from Python, but have the process end when the user closes the window?

Tags: python, process

I want to write a Python script which will start a GUI program (as in, run a binary program with `subprocess.run` or `os.system` or something). The script should not block until the program is done, it should start it and then keep running.

I'm doing this on Ubuntu.

I tried `subprocess.Popen`, but if I run, say `subprocess.Popen("gedit")`, I get strange behavior. If I open the Ubuntu system monitor (process manager), I can see that the gedit process appears when I run the script, and the gedit window itself opens. But if I close the window, the process doesn't end in the system monitor. The process stays there until my python script exits.

How can I get the behavior I want? The only thing I can think of right now is to just call `subprocess.run` in a different Python thread, is that the only thing I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `subprocess.call`. This has worked for me before.

```
subprocess.call(['command', 'arguments'])
```

The program should end when the window is closed.

Comment: `subprocess.call` is blocking, which I don't want.

Comment: true. you could use concurrent programming tho. just a suggestion

Answer (score -1):

You have to kill the subprocess you've created before you exit the program.

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19448255/5443053).