# How to close file explorer window using Python

Tags: python, operating-system

I've used os to open a folder location. I then want to wait a few seconds before closing that same window.

I've tried using os.close(), but I get an error.

```
    import os
    import pause

    path = "C:/Users"
    path=os.path.realpath(path)
    os.startfile(path)

    pause.seconds(5)

    os.close(path)
```

I expect the newly opened folder window to be closed after pausing for 5 seconds.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: You're probably better off starting explorer.exe with the subprocess module and then killing the child process when you need to. See the answer to the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447603/how-to-kill-a-python-child-process-created-with-subprocess-check-output-when-t

Comment: The error is "an integer is required (got type str)"

Comment: os.close() is what you use to close a file; you cannot stop a process (explorer) this way. See my other comment.