# How to kill a docker created with python subprocess.Popen() when the parent dies?

Tags: python, linux, docker, subprocess

I have a python script as a "service manager" to run multiple docker containers. I already handled graceful shutdown (cltr+c). However when I `pkill -9` the python script, the dockers are still running.

```
libc = ctypes.CDLL("libc.so.6")
def set_pdeathsig(sig=signal.SIGTERM):
    def callback():
        return libc.prctl(1, sig)
    return callback

open_container_cmd = "docker-compose run --rm -d test"
proc = subprocess.Popen(
                open_container_cmd,
                shell=True,
                stdout=open(os.devnull, 'wb'),
                preexec_fn=set_pdeathsig(signal.SIGTERM))
```

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19448096/10412708) but no luck. I even tried executing in terminal `kill -9 pid` to kill docker container with process ID from `proc = subprocess.Popen(open_container_cmd); proc.pid` but it won't even stop the container.

Comment: Remove the `-d` from the command. Or use a docker cimmand to stop the container.

Comment: @KlausD. didn't work

Comment: Which? And how exactly did you implement it?

Comment: i removed -d.. how do I "use a docker cimmand to stop the container"?

Comment: @KlausD. oh actually it's working. now the problem is the subprocess is interfering with the parent. Example I'm having weird spaces on my print lines and if i ctrl+c, the docker-compose reads it rather than the main script..

Comment: @KlausD. its working, just have to update/add `stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,`! Thanks man!