# External programs are running when multiprocessing Python is closed

Tags: python, subprocess, multiprocessing

In Python (3.5), I started running external executables (written in C++) by multiprocessing.Pool.map + subprocess from an Xshell connection. However, the Xshell connection is interrupted due to bad internet condition.

After connecting again, I see that the managing Python is gone but the C++ executables are still running (and it looks like in the correct way, the Pool seems still control them.)

The question is if this is a bug, and what I shall do in this case. I cannot `kill` or `kill -9` them.

**Add**: after removing all `sublst_file` by hand, all running executables(`cmd`) are gone. It seems that `except sub.SubprocessError as e:` part is still working.

The basic frame of my program is outlined in the following.

```
import subprocess as sub
import multiprocessing as mp
import itertools as it
import os
import time

def chunks(lst, chunksize=5):
    return it.zip_longest(*[iter(lst)]*chunksize)

class Work():
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.lst = lst

    def _work(self, sublst):
       retry_times = 6
       for i in range(retry_times):
             try:
                 cmd = 'my external c++ cmd'
                 sublst_file = 'a config file generated from sublst'
                 sub.check_call([cmd, sublst_file])
                 os.remove(sublst_file)
                 return sublst # return success sublst
             except sub.SubprocessError as e:
                 if i == (retry_times-1):
                    print('\n[ERROR] %s %s failed after %d tries\n' % (cmd, sublst_file, retry_times))
                    return []
                 else:
                     print('\n[WARNNING] %dth sleeping, please waiting for restart\n' % (i+1))
                     time.sleep(1+i)

    def work(self):
        with mp.Pool(4) as pool:
            results = pool.map(self._work, chunks(self.lst, 5))
        for r in it.chain(results):
            # other work on success items
            print(r)
```

Comment: It isn't too vague but I needed to read it a few times to fully grasp what you are actually doing, might be helpful to add a few lines of code that demonstrates how you are starting the connections in python.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I have added my code. I guess the problem is caused by the retry part.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's your responsibility to clean up if something goes wrong. Why exactly can't you kill the child processes?

Comment: @Phillip They just didn't die.

Comment: If `kill -9` does not work, the most likely explanation is that you tried killing the wrong process or as the wrong user. For others, see [e.g. here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5642/what-if-kill-9-does-not-work). `kill()`ing the children in a SIGTERM handler is the right thing to do and should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `multiprocessing.Pool` does terminate its workers upon `terminate()` which is also called by `__del__` which in turn will be called upon module unload (at exit).

The reason why these guys are orphaned is because `subprocess.check_call` spawns are not terminated upon exit.

This fact is not mentioned explicitly in the reference, but there is no indication anywhere that the spawns are terminated. A brief review of the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/subprocess.py) also left me with no findings. This behavior is also easily testable.

To clean up upon parent termination use the `Popen` interface and this answer [Killing child process when parent crashes in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14128410/killing-child-process-when-parent-crashes-in-python/14128476#14128476)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The part about `multiprocess` is well documented, so I assume you mean the second part about `subprocess`. It's not said explicitly, but there is no indication anywhere in the reference doc that the spawns are terminated. A brief review of the source code also left me with no findings.