# Exit while-looped child process when parent process is exited?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, pyserial, panda3d

I'm trying to close child process(which is doing while loop) when parent process is exited (Whenever parent process is clean-exit, forced-exit or exited because of exception) not to make child process a zombie process.

I'm making a game that communicates with Arduino (using serial), and main process is running Panda3D's ShowBase instance(Game engine, do render and another many things) so main must not be stopped.
So, I created subprocess using multiprocessing module so that main process is safe from stopping to wait serial in.

But the problem is, when i close Panda3D window, call sys.exit() or exited because of exception, main process exits immediately, and can't join or give false to subprocess, so subprocess becomes zombie.

I have no idea how to solve this. What should i do to make it work as i expected?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from panda3d.core import *

class HW_support:
    def hardware_event_handler(self, process_status):
        self.process_alive = True
        while self.process_alive:
            print('Working!')
            self.process_alive = process_status.get()
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from direct.showbase.ShowBase import ShowBase
    import sys
    class TestApp(ShowBase):
        def __init__(self):
            ShowBase.__init__(self)
            self.process_status_argv = Queue()
            self.HW_sub_process = Process(target = HW_support().hardware_event_handler, args=(self.process_status_argv,))
            self.HW_sub_process.start()
            base.messenger.toggleVerbose()
            taskMgr.add(self.task_make_alive, 'task_make_alive')

            base.accept('escape', self.exit_taskloop)
        def exit_taskloop(self, task=None):
            taskMgr.stop()

        def task_make_alive(self, task=None):
            self.process_status_argv.put(True)
            return task.cont

    app = TestApp()
    app.run()
    #app.HW_sub_process.join()
    app.process_status_argv.put(False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the main program add this at the top (well below `import multiprocessing`)

```
if multiprocessing.current_process().name == 'MainProcess':
    import atexit
    atexit.register(lambda *a : os.remove("running.txt"))
    open("running.txt","wb").close()
```

in the subprocces change your `while True` loop to `while os.path.exists("running.txt"):`

alternatively you could have atexit place a message in the queue or do whatever to signal to the subprocess that it should exit.

Comment: This is very interesting idea...i'll try it right now, Thanks!

Comment: note that as the block at the top i think `if __name__ == "__main__"` would work also ... I just wanted it to be very clear what the purpose of the if block was

Comment: This works! And as you said, placing it in if __name__ == "__main__" would be better.(for JUST IN CASE) Anyway, Thanks bro!

Answer (score 1):

Multiple processes makes things a lot more complicated.

To shut down the HW_support process cleanly, you need to send it the message via your `Queue` object, then the parent needs to `join()` it (wait for it to exit) before exiting itself.

Anything that could make the parent exit unexpectedly (console interrupt, thrown exception, `sys.exit`, etc etc) will need to be carefully caught and managed so that you can still cleanly shut down the child before exiting.

Comment: Umm...then is it a good idea to add function to subprocess that investigates main process is alive and if it's dead, exit itself? I'm also considering not to use multiprocessing, but i don't have no idea either :-P

Comment: Another answer suggests using a file for that purpose, which could work.  An older question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25542110/kill-child-process-if-parent-is-killed-in-python) has some good tips, including setting the child to 'daemon mode' which will cause it to be killed when the parent is killed.

Comment: Oh, that way has a value of experiment. I'll try that way later, though solution that uses a file works great :-) Anyway, Thanks for answering!

Comment: setting it to daemon is really probably the right answer :P I think ... lol not sure why i didnt think of that

Comment: I just tried this and working seamless! Setting subprocess as demon is also a nice and cool idea.