# Subprocessing in python

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to invoke infinite loop script from parent code.

```
from subprocess import Popen
import subprocess
import os
import sys
proc=subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, os.getcwd()+'/A.py'],shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(proc.communicate())
print('Hi')
```

and my script is:

```
import time

def main():
    while True:
        print('HI2')
        time.sleep(3)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()`
```

but it does not work and does Popen block the script. I mean that why print('Hi') syntax does not work.

Answer (score 1):

`proc.communitcate()` waits for `proc` to finish. It then returns the output from the subprocess.

In this example out is the output printed on stdout and err the output on stderr:

```
out, err = proc.communicate()
```

If you don't need the output, simple skip the `communicate()`.

Comment: Would you tell me how to terminate infinite child subprocess?

Comment: You should be able to use `proc.terminate()`for that

Comment: Thank you for your answer. E subprocess invoke script, and within each script there are multiprocess. While I terminate parent process(I mean closing the script) the children process are still alive!!!

Comment: How do you close the script? Let it run till it terminates by itself? Or do you use something like CTRL + C?

Comment: If you want to have child processes automatically terminated, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884941/killing-the-children-with-the-parent)